# what do these error messages mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

i'm in section 9 of the hartl rails tutorial, this def isn't making sense.  thoughts?

```
1) User pages index 
 Failure/Error: visit users_path
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
 # ./app/helpers/users_helper.rb:3:in `gravatar_for'
 # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_users_index_html_erb__3004047397113020476_70255017945740'
 # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `each'
 # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb__3004047397113020476_70255017945740'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'



2) User pages index should list each user
 Failure/Error: visit users_path
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
 # ./app/helpers/users_helper.rb:3:in `gravatar_for'
 # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_users_index_html_erb__3004047397113020476_70255017945740'
 # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `each'
 # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb__3004047397113020476_70255017945740'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Seems like you're calling `gravatar_for` with 2 arguments, and it should be one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Chapter 7's first exercise](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec%3asignup_exercises) specifies that you extend the `gravatar_for` method to include a new, optional parameter for including size. You likely didn't do this exercise and so it is only expecting the original 1 argument as opposed to both arguments. Complete the exercise and you should get this code to pass.

Answer (score 1):

In Your user_helper.rb file in helper folder you are passing 2 arguments instead of 1 for **gravatar_for** method. If you put code of that it would be much easier to solve.